# std::condition_variable::wait_until function

Tags: c++, c++11, condition-variable, stdthread

I have a small question about using this method.
Will my thread wake up if the `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()` is greater then the second parameter(`abs_time`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Section 30.2.4 [thread.req.timing] (more-or-less accurate version available at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3128.html#thread.req.timing) says:

> if Ca > Ct, the waiting function should wake as soon as possible, i.e.
>   Ca + Di + Dm, since the timeout is already satisfied.

So the answer to your question is "yes".